# vertically aligning button in a two column layout

Tags: css, layout, styles, vertical-alignment

I'm attempting to get a two column layout, where the left column has a button (vertically centered) and the right column is simply text.

I have been able to get the two column layout working, but I cannot get the button centered (the biggest text is dynamic. it can grow and shrink, so the left column needs to be `height: 100%`).

This what what I have come up with so far:

```
<body>
<div>
<div style="float: left; width: 10px; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
    <button type="button" style="display: block; vertical-align: middle;">Abc</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla magna, auctor a varius quis, convallis id est. Vestibulum rhoncus, diam ac malesuada commodo, ipsum justo blandit nulla, eu pretium felis metus vel erat. Donec lobortis arcu ac mauris aliquam ultrices. Nunc feugiat, nisl non pharetra tempus, nunc est cursus nibh, quis hendrerit nibh mauris et massa. Nunc justo quam, feugiat ac mattis ac, placerat sed sem. Sed ultrices orci at erat sodales malesuada. Aenean blandit blandit tellus sit amet imperdiet. Duis pellentesque augue quis lacus cursus at convallis dolor volutpat. Donec orci quam, rhoncus in tincidunt ornare, fringilla eget magna.

Nulla facilisi. Cras consectetur turpis id odio mattis sagittis. Aenean bibendum, ligula tempor luctus fringilla, magna neque malesuada ipsum, non tincidunt ipsum libero non ante. Mauris posuere ullamcorper lorem, et vulputate nibh mattis a. Mauris pretium ullamcorper convallis. Mauris quam est, sollicitudin ut pretium eu, mollis ut elit. Nulla vulputate sodales sagittis.

Suspendisse a porta orci. Sed velit purus, auctor quis tincidunt sed, tristique sed libero. Sed et est eget neque mattis lobortis. Mauris suscipit vestibulum gravida. Etiam lorem ligula, viverra eu iaculis vel, varius at libero. Nullam ante ligula, porta vel euismod ac, gravida ac massa. Pellentesque semper eros vitae sapien aliquam laoreet quis ut neque. Phasellus ac ullamcorper nibh. Praesent vitae tellus libero. Sed aliquet consectetur tempor. Nam porta ornare quam, sed viverra arcu congue eget. Nulla pharetra mi ac enim convallis vel mollis nunc iaculis.

Aenean cursus sodales nunc eu euismod. Mauris eget justo est, eget varius libero. Integer pretium ultricies tortor, ut pellentesque dolor bibendum sed. Praesent ullamcorper, est facilisis molestie ultricies, erat metus tristique enim, nec luctus quam felis et lacus. Donec ullamcorper nulla ac purus consequat aliquet. Praesent nec arcu eu orci feugiat ullamcorper sit amet ac augue. Nullam porta adipiscing felis, vel suscipit tortor bibendum vel. Cras tincidunt erat quis mi ornare ultricies.

Maecenas non ante elit, vel ullamcorper sem. Donec a lectus sit amet lectus lacinia fermentum. Quisque at feugiat lorem. Donec in ipsum lectus, in aliquet enim. Duis purus nisi, tempor vehicula faucibus eu, dapibus id nisl. Phasellus dignissim sodales ornare. Fusce vel libero non ipsum sagittis convallis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce ultrices, lectus nec eleifend porttitor, risus sem tincidunt elit, eu hendrerit nibh tortor a dolor.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

and to my understanding should be working, but does not seem to be. Any suggestions on how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with solution to put your content into `div` with `position: relative` and making `button` `position: absolute` with `top: 50%`. Is that what you want to achieve? 
[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/65F7K/)

Comment: yeah if you know the height of `button` you could do `margin-top: -5px` or whatever half the height is, that will align it perfectly.

Comment: This in combination with @JakeZeitz suggestion for `margin-top` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should make the container display: table and remove the float from the button:

```
<div style="display: table;">
<div style="width: 10px; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell;">
    <button type="button" style="display: block; vertical-align: middle;">Abc</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris nulla magna, auctor a varius quis, convallis id est. Vestibulum rhoncus, diam ac malesuada commodo, ipsum justo blandit nulla, eu pretium felis metus vel erat. Donec lobortis arcu ac mauris aliquam ultrices. Nunc feugiat, nisl non pharetra tempus, nunc est cursus nibh, quis hendrerit nibh mauris et massa. Nunc justo quam, feugiat ac mattis ac, placerat sed sem. Sed ultrices orci at erat sodales malesuada. Aenean blandit blandit tellus sit amet imperdiet. Duis pellentesque augue quis lacus cursus at convallis dolor volutpat. Donec orci quam, rhoncus in tincidunt ornare, fringilla eget magna.

Nulla facilisi. Cras consectetur turpis id odio mattis sagittis. Aenean bibendum, ligula tempor luctus fringilla, magna neque malesuada ipsum, non tincidunt ipsum libero non ante. Mauris posuere ullamcorper lorem, et vulputate nibh mattis a. Mauris pretium ullamcorper convallis. Mauris quam est, sollicitudin ut pretium eu, mollis ut elit. Nulla vulputate sodales sagittis.

Suspendisse a porta orci. Sed velit purus, auctor quis tincidunt sed, tristique sed libero. Sed et est eget neque mattis lobortis. Mauris suscipit vestibulum gravida. Etiam lorem ligula, viverra eu iaculis vel, varius at libero. Nullam ante ligula, porta vel euismod ac, gravida ac massa. Pellentesque semper eros vitae sapien aliquam laoreet quis ut neque. Phasellus ac ullamcorper nibh. Praesent vitae tellus libero. Sed aliquet consectetur tempor. Nam porta ornare quam, sed viverra arcu congue eget. Nulla pharetra mi ac enim convallis vel mollis nunc iaculis.

Aenean cursus sodales nunc eu euismod. Mauris eget justo est, eget varius libero. Integer pretium ultricies tortor, ut pellentesque dolor bibendum sed. Praesent ullamcorper, est facilisis molestie ultricies, erat metus tristique enim, nec luctus quam felis et lacus. Donec ullamcorper nulla ac purus consequat aliquet. Praesent nec arcu eu orci feugiat ullamcorper sit amet ac augue. Nullam porta adipiscing felis, vel suscipit tortor bibendum vel. Cras tincidunt erat quis mi ornare ultricies.

Maecenas non ante elit, vel ullamcorper sem. Donec a lectus sit amet lectus lacinia fermentum. Quisque at feugiat lorem. Donec in ipsum lectus, in aliquet enim. Duis purus nisi, tempor vehicula faucibus eu, dapibus id nisl. Phasellus dignissim sodales ornare. Fusce vel libero non ipsum sagittis convallis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Fusce ultrices, lectus nec eleifend porttitor, risus sem tincidunt elit, eu hendrerit nibh tortor a dolor.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:table; width:100%; height:100%">

    <div style="display:table-cell; width:20%; height:100%; background:#ddd; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
         <button type="button">Abc</button>
    </div>

    <div style="display:table-cell; height:100%; padding-left:20px">
         Your content
    </div>

</div>
```

You need just look at this - `http://jsfiddle.net/qN53h/`

This will resolved your issue. There is *height 100%* issue for display table-cell. For that fix you may try `height:auto` or make a fix height for parent display table div or child display table cell div, like this - `http://jsfiddle.net/CjT2G/`